# get frame of a view after use mas_makeConstraints

Tags: ios, debugging, masonry, objective-c-category

**Masonry** is a useful framework in iOS.And I want to use it to make a category for UIView.

But after using the function "**mas_makeConstraints()**" to set the frame ,I can't get the frame of the view.The frame of the view still is {0,0,0,0}.

So when does the value change in the program? or what the basic principle in **Masonry**? Or how can I get the frame in debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `mas_makeConstraints` on your view simply adds constraints to it. Your view's frame will be updated during next layout cycle, not immediately. In order to force layout, you can try calling `layoutIfNeeded` on your view instance after setting up constraints.